# Confusion related to prediction

Tags: bayesian, self-study, monte-carlo

I was referring to this video lecture http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_murray_mcmc/ where the speaker had something like this

$$
p(x|D) = \int P(x|\theta,D)P(\theta,D)d\theta
$$

equivalent to

$$
\frac{1}{S}\sum_{s=1}^S P(x|\theta^{(s)},D), \theta^{(s)} \sim P(\theta|D) 
$$

I didn't get how the average was derived and why is $\theta^{(s)} \sim P(\theta|D) $
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Do you recognize the formula for $p(x|D)$ as an *expectation* and the set of $\theta^{(s)}$ as an iid *sample*? If so, you might see that the two expressions are not precisely equivalent, but that the latter *estimates* the former based on the sample. If so, the question comes down to why one may replace $P(\theta,D)$ by $P(\theta|D)$ when everything is conditioned on $D$.

Comment: @whuber. No, I didn't get what you mean by p(x|D) is an expectation, it is probability isn't it. Expectation is something that you get when you multiply f(x)*p(x). I am just a beginner. So can you please provide some clarifications?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_continuous_random_variable.

Comment: @Whuber. I do get what expectation and probability is but my question is how come p(x|D) is expectation in the above case it is probability isn't it?

Comment: The trick is to do pattern matching: Writing $g(\theta)=P(x|\theta,D)$ and $f(\theta)=P(\theta,D)$, the definition of $p(x|D)$ becomes $\int g(\theta) f(\theta) d\ \theta$. Now using the letter "$x$" instead of $\theta$ gives you precisely Wikipedia's definition of $E(g(x))$.  Reverting to the original meanings of $x$ and $\theta$, this is the expected value of $P(x|\theta,D)$--thought of as a function of $\theta$--when the probability law for $\theta$ is given by the density $P(\theta,D)$.

Comment: @wuhber can we discuss in chat. I think I got some of it. But it would be better if I could ask more in chat. Is it possible wuhber?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6079/discussion-between-user34790-and-whuber)

Answer (score 3):

May I use a slightly different (but still sloppy, confusing random objects with their realizations, etc.) notation? I didn't watch the lecture, but it seems that you know the value of $n$ observations $(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x^{(n)}$, and you are interested in the predictive density $f(x_{n+1}\mid x^{(n)})$. Marginalizing, using the product rule, and using the fact that $x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}$ are conditionally iid given $\theta$, we have
$$
  f(x_{n+1}\mid x^{(n)}) = \int f(x_{n+1},\theta\mid x^{(n)})\,d\theta = \int f(x_{n+1}\mid\theta,x^{(n)})\,\pi(\theta\mid x^{(n)})\,d\theta
$$
$$
  = \int f(x_{n+1}\mid\theta)\,\pi(\theta\mid x^{(n)})\,d\theta = (*)
$$
Please, be sure that you understand the three equalities above. The last integral is
the integral of "stuff" times a density (the posterior), so it is the expectation of "stuff"
$$
  (*) = \mathbb{E}\left[f(x_{n+1}\mid\Phi)\right] \, ,
$$
where the distribution of $\Phi$ has density $\pi(\,\cdot\mid x^{(n)})$.

Suppose that you have a sequence of iid random variables $\Phi_1,\Phi_2,\dots$, such that $\Phi_i\sim\Phi$. By the strong law of large numbers
$$
  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_{n+1}\mid\Phi_i) \to \mathbb{E}\left[f(x_{n+1}\mid\Phi)\right] \, ,
$$
almost surely, as $N\to\infty$.

Actually, if you are doing MCMC, your sequence of $\Phi_i$'s (a Markov chain) will be a dependent sequence, but given some regularity conditions that the chain satisfies, the Ergodic Theorem guarantees that you have the almost sure convergence described above.

Comment: (+1) @zen. I believe $N$ is the size of the $i.i.d.$ sample of $(\Phi_i)_{1\leq i\leq N}$ and the $a.s.$ convergence is indeed for $N \rightarrow \infty$ with **fixed** $n$. This is just to mention that you do not have a convergence theorem for (*) as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in the general case...Therefore the reader should really differenciate what pertains to $n$ (the number of measurements) and what pertains to $N$ (the sample size of simulated data from the posterior distribution).

Comment: Yes. I'm taking $N\to\infty$ for some fixed $n$. Did you understand it differently?

Comment: No, all is good. just: $N$ (capital n) is not defined and the fact that you have 2 "n" notations (caps and small) with 2 potential levels of convergence --> could be misinterpreted...